# Android - Where does barcode scanner (zxing) parse HTML

Tags: android, zxing

I'm writing an app which calls barcode scanner via intents, and right now... I'm trying to figure out where in the ZXing codebase they parse HTML.  Basically, I want to know where the product result UI is drawn and where they get the avg price for an item.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[ProductResultInfoRetriever.java](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/supplement/ProductResultInfoRetriever.java) would be a good place to start.

FYI, Google's code search is pretty decent.  I found it by going to the zxing site, clicking the "source" tab, typing "Http" into the the search box, and hitting "search trunk" button :)